# iOS: how to embed audio into pdf

Tags: ios, pdf, audio, pdf-generation

Ok, so I've created a pdf programmatically using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile`, `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo` and the appropriate Core Graphics calls -- so far, no sweat.

But now I want to add an audio link.  Not just a hypertext link to an audio file, but I'd like to somehow embed some sort of active control such that the user can press `PLAY` and the audio will play.

Is that possible?  What are the relevant APIs?  Is there a good tutorial describing what I want to do?  Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. As of this writing, we're at iOS 7.1, though PDF-generation has been around since well before iOS4, so I'm not sure that matters.

Comment: Have you done a Google search on "embedding audio in pdf"?

Comment: I have.  Have you?!  ;)  (Just kidding.  Maybe my Google-fu is weak, but I couldn't find anything about how to do it *programmatically in iOS*.  Lots of links for how to do it in Acrobat-Pro, etc.)  Thanks!

Comment: My point was, once you find out how to do it in general (it seems like it requires special tools), then maybe you could find a corresponding iOS solution. There's no iOS specific API just for audio in a PDF but perhaps it's just a matter of writing certain data a certain way.

Comment: (And Maddy: thanks for the edit.  I read the tag descriptionss more carefully and see my mistake -- learned something, today! :)  )

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not seeing anything about how it's done, programmatically.  It's not as if Acrobat Pro source code is out there (is it?!  I couldn't find that, either :D)  Again, maybe you're a better Googler than I, but I did some searching before asking SO.

Comment: In addition: clearly it can be done, since we see PDFs with audio PLAY buttons.  And also, pretty clearly, the answer isn't on SO so, once we find the answer, we'll post it here, and SO is improved.  Yay!  :)

Comment: FYI - There is an iPad app (PDF Expert) that appears to be able to embed multimedia into PDFs. So there must be a way. Also see [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com). Better yet - https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit